# First Post review queue going ridiculously big. Need more reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review

Half a year ago I raised [a similar Meta post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2352/205764), and very fortunately the queues has been kept at a reasonable size (10~40) since then.

I just checked back here and WHOA!

[image]

The queue has far overtaken Stack Overflow's!

In the past 2~3 months I'm very glad to have seen new users becoming active and avid, as well as their generous help with this site by participating in the review queues. But it was only "the past few months", not today (and the near future, I'm afraid).

What happened to the queue(s)?

Comment: One contributing factor might be that I've been ignoring that queue, to let the community have more of a chance: I don't think the site needs moderators to be monopolising all the queues.

Comment: @DanHulme Yeah I agree mods shouldn't be taking care of *everything*, but still, isn't the queue too big?

Comment: I've been off for a while. Will resume reviewing soon.

Comment: Not gonna touch it myself for the reasons already made clear in the last Meta post. I do skim through the day's posts when I log on and flag/vote as appropriate though.

Comment: @AndyYan Makes sense. We could use a bot for the FP queue.